# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to create a sharepoint workbench, but after following all directions from microsoft docs and video to torials. I have also used 
npm config set proxy http://proxyaddress.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxyaddress.com:8080
just in case network was getting in the way.
Anyone happen to know what direction i should take with this error?

[Full Error]

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules@microsoft\sp-webpart-workbench' -> 'H:\helloworld-webpart\temp\workbench-packages@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench'
    at Object.symlinkSync (fs.js:909:3)

```
at WorkbenchPage._getUrlForWorkbenchPackagePath (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-webpart-workbench\lib\api\WorkbenchPage.js:206:17)

at WorkbenchPage._generateWorkbenchPageContent (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-webpart-workbench\lib\api\WorkbenchPage.js:72:39)

at WorkbenchPage.handleWorkbenchRequest (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-webpart-workbench\lib\api\WorkbenchPage.js:26:51)

at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

at next (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)

at Route.dispatch (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)

at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

at H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22

at Function.process_params (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)

at next (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

at _setJSONResponseContentTypeMiddleware (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-serve\lib\ServeTask.js:119:9)

at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

at trim_prefix (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)

at H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7

at Function.process_params (H:\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

references:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue was that I installed to the wrong directory. I installed on a shared drive and not the local drive.